# Firebird: incompatible wire encryption between server and client

Tags: c#, database, encryption, server, firebird

I am trying to access a Firebird server and when I try to open it via my C# application I get an exception saying incompatible wire encryption between server and user.

```
public void Connector(string command)
{
    FbConnectionStringBuilder csb = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
    csb.DataSource = "localhost";
    //csb.Port = 3050;
    csb.Database = String.Format(@"{0}/database/database.fdb", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    csb.UserID = "SYSDBA";
    csb.Password = "masterkey";
    csb.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;

    FbConnection db = new FbConnection(csb.ToString());

    db.Open();

    FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(command, db);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I tried to run it as administrator, change config file of Firebird itself but none of it worked. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Which version of the Firebird ado.net provider do you use, which settings did you change? By the sound of it you still have WireEncryption set to Required.

Comment: WyreCrypt is set to enabled only. I am running ado provider 5.0. The exception is on db.Open();

Comment: Make sure it is set to `Enabled` (capital E), and that it isn't prefixed with `#` (comment/use default), and that you have edited the `firebird.conf` in the Firebird server folder.

Comment: Done! It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove the `#`! Thank you